How can I add AUD cash to My Yahoo Finance Portfolio
I have built a stock portfolio in Yahoo Finance. I want to show my available AUD cash along with my individual stocks. How do I show my available AUD cash in my Yahoo Finance stock portfolio? I have tried "$$" and "$$CASH", but neither works.
Thank you.
Lewis
